# How to autoresize the subviews for screen orientations in iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, screen-orientation

I have created a UIViewController class with a background color as red.
I have also created a UIView which is a subview and placed with a background image and two UIButtons on them.
The coding which i give for screen orientation is

```
 -(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}

self.view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
self.view.backgroundcolor =[UIColor redColor];
UIView *subview;
subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
subview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoResizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Problem:

When i turn into Landscape the subview is resized with the image, but the buttons remain in the same position and i am not using any .xib file.I have created the project programmatically.Please do reply....

Answer (score 0):

Override [`layoutSubviews`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews) for your class. You might need to explicitly call `[self setNeedsLayout]` from  `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also have another problem where i have another subview as TableView where it appears in the click of the UIButton. When i turn it into landscape, the Tableview is turned but not fits into the whole screen.Half of the screen i can see the TableView and the other half is my rootView.Please do reply me .